# Websockets on Node-server hosted in Azure fails

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, socket.io, ws

I have a barebone simple example that works locally but not in Azure. My original question was a bit specific to an cors-error, that i have now worked around, and therefor edited away that part. But i still cant manage to make WS work on azure. And i need help.;

```
var server = http.Server(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({server});

server.listen(8070, () => {
  console.log("Listening on " + port)
});


wss.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg)
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({hey:'you'}))
  })
});
```

client connection-string:

```
SOCKET_ENDPOINT = 'wss://******.azurewebsites.net/';
```

I've turned on websockets in my app-configuration.

EDIT:

So i have now turned every stone. Even switched library from socket.io to ws. Same problem. I came a little further i think when trying different things, now i get following error "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://*******.azurewebsites.net:8070/."

Edit2:
The http-upgrade is fine
[image]

Here's the error
[image]

Edit 3: Curl command:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to *******.azurewebsites.net (20.40.202.6) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.azurewebsites.net
*  start date: Sep 28 19:00:01 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 28 19:00:01 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "********.azurewebsites.net" matched cert's "*.azurewebsites.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Microsoft Corporation; CN=Microsoft RSA TLS CA 01
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /socket.io/?EIO=4 HTTP/1.1
> Host: *********.azurewebsites.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Kestrel
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="********.azurewebsites.net" authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/<tenant>/oauth2/authorize" resource_id="<resource>"
< Date: Tue, 22 Jun 2021 05:56:15 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host *******.azurewebsites.net left intact
```

Comment: This is a server-side issue. Did you add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on your endpoint? It should be: Access-Control-Allow-Origin=<your-domain-of-your-site-thats-calling-websocket-endpoint>

Comment: Im using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors and it works for my REST-endpoints

Comment: Application-logs says that port 8080 already is in use.

Comment: Updated my answer @pixelbits . I dont think cors is the problem.

Comment: but the error message...

Comment: @pixelbits yes, but now i don't have the cors-error anymore. I think that came because something else failed (it happens).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you host your app in **Azure AppService**?

Make sure you have websocket option turned on in platform:
[image]

**AppService resource -> Settings -> General settings tab -> Platform settings section**

Comment: Yes, that is on.

Comment: also i use App service authentication with AAD.

Comment: I asked on ws's github here :  https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1905
something to do with the authentication it seems. How do i go about that?